# Large delay when earning reputation back from deleted question

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-questions

Whenever I do a question and it receives a large number of downvotes, I usually tend to delete them instead of editing, as I am nervous about losing my reputation. From my past experience with Stack Exchange, I always knew that deleting questions can get your reputation back.

Oddly enough, when you delete a question in hopes of earning your reputation back, it will take a long period of time to earn it back. Earning your reputation can take about several minutes to half an hour.

Should this issue with having to wait a long amount of time be fixed?

Comment: According to [Recent Reputation History Changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes), this is intentional: "*reputation sync takes up to 5 minutes on a delete/undelete action; as to not block the user's response thread, it's offloaded to a background queue*".

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog, In the post it says: "takes up to 5 minutes", in my questions it takes more than 5 minutes. I don't know if this could be a duplicate. Can you help some more?

Comment: They've probably changed up the timing of that script since that post was made, but the *reason* why such a script exists is still the same.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog This solved my question, but I'll check with a mod if this has changed.

Comment: If it is offloaded to a background queue then I suspect that the 5 minutes it takes won't begin until the reputation sync gets to the front of that queue.

Comment: Worth pointing out that just because you deleted the question that was downvoted, does not mean, it won’t be used to determine if your able to ask questions.  It’s also best to improve a question instead of deleting it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not think that this is a bug.

To me a delay of 15-30 minutes between deleting a post and seeing any reputation changes on it reversed seems reasonable because those reputation changes are probably performed by a script that runs every 15-30 minutes.